# How to Save as PDF automatically when doing the Mail Merge (VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

When I am trying to run the code below the following happens:

1) It opens a "Save PDF File As" Window

2) I have to manually type in the name

3) The code runs

I want to automate steps 1 and 2 so that the code runs without any manual inputs from me and saves it as whatever.pdf in whatever path.

I tried using ExportAsFixedFormat but the problem is that it is saving only the first page as pdf and the remaining 100+ records that are going through the mail merge are not being saved. On top of that, it still opens that Dialog Window from step 1.

```
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFilename:=whatever.pdf, _
                                   ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, etc.
```

The code:

```
Sub DoMailMerge()

Set myMerge = ActiveDocument.MailMerge
If myMerge.State = wdMainAndSourceAndHeader Or _
 myMerge.State = wdMainAndDataSource Then
 With myMerge.DataSource
 .FirstRecord = 1
 .LastRecord = 3
 End With
End If
With myMerge
 .Destination = wdSendToPrinter
 .Execute
End With

End Sub
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The code under "The code:" can't be the full code? It performs no save action - it only sends the merge result (three records) to the printer. You need to show the full code that's causing the behavior you describe, as a block. But FWIW you need to research saving a merge to separate documents - this is not something mail merge knows how to do. There are various approaches described in full detail that can be found on the Internet.

Comment: This kind of thing has been addressed many times on many different web sites. See, for example, *Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files* and *Run a Mailmerge from Excel, Sending the Output to Individual Files* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** threads at:
http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html
and: 
http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/163017-Word-Mailmerge-Tips-amp-Tricks

Comment: Thanks for the link, however, I don't need to save it to individual pdf files. I need 1 final PDF final with all the records in it. For example, my list has 500 names and addresses and let's say 300 live in Asia, 100 in Europe and 100 in North America. I need the code to mail merge those fields and save only 3 pdf files (Asia.pdf with 300 records, Europe.pdf with 100 records, NA.pdf with 100 records).

Answer (score -2):

[Edit] Corrected object reference. Added SaveAs2

In the OP, an attempt is made to use a pseudo printer to save as a pdf. There are differences between the SaveAs pdf format and the variety of pdf pseudo printers. Is there a reason for printing to a PDF and saving that file, rather than doing a Save As and choosing the PDF format?

```
With myMerge
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .Execute
End With
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 "path & filename", wdFormatPDF
```

The following is sometimes needed to silence prompting with scripted saves. For the above tested method, there were no prompts, so it may not be needed.

Toggle off `.DisplayAlerts` before SaveAs

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 "path & filename", wdFormatPDF
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
```

Or

```
Dim tempDisplayAlerts As Long
tempDisplayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts  
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 "path & filename", wdFormatPDF    
Application.DisplayAlerts = tempDisplayAlerts
```

Comment: First of all, ActiveDocument.DisplayAlerts throws an error because I believe it is should be Application.DisplayAlerts and second of all, even if it worked it still does not resolve the issue of saving the merged file (with all the 100+ records) as pdf.

Comment: Application.DisplayAlerts = False also kills any mailmerge from a document that is opened while that setting is active.